# ThreadPoolExecutor not Working Properly with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, concurrent.futures

When I requests a long list of urls from ThreadPoolExecutor I am encountering a problem where it seems like the request isn't being sent. I am expecting json responses from the urls

```
urls = ["example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"] #My list is about 1,500 urls long

def load_url(url):
    print("here")
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.json())
    return r

def main():
    urls = ["example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"] #My list is about 1,500 urls long

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(
            load_url, url): url for url in urls}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            print("right here")
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                response = future.result()
            except (HTTPError, ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout):
                print("fail")

            else:   
                print(response.json())

main()
```

When I execute the following code, only the first url's request seems to have been sent and received by the as_completed function. The rest, despite printing "here" and the correct urls and the correct json response (from the load_url function), they are not sent to the as_completed function. So, it's printing "here" continuously but not "right here".

My python version is 3.9.1

Comment: are you observing the issue when you have 1500 URLs or even on a smaller count say 20 or so? delay on "right here" will be based on the request's response. So printing of "here" for sure will be continuous and fast, while "right here" will take time and depends on response time and other factors like network latency etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I figured it out... or at least it's working the way I want it to work. The api calls were successful, but for some reason when I returned the response object to the as_completed, in practice it never returned. What works now is I am only returning the information from the response I need to the as_completed. Plus, I added some rate limiting. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: appreciated for keeping us posted! glad that you have resolved this.